# get full current crontab line, and create unique result email headers (from, subject, etc) per line

Tags: linux, perl, email, cron, pipe

I have a giant crontab with many scripts on a linux machine.  I need to be able to a) change the subject and/or from of cronjob result emails, because the default is unreadably long.  b) Do so via a centralized solution. c) Only require minimal changes to the crontab itself.

For example this crontab line:

```
0 */3 * * * /path/to/script1 | /path/to/script2 | /path/to/script3
```

Creates this email subject:

```
Cron <cronuser@myserver> /path/to/script1 | /path/to/script2 | /path/to/script3
```

Which in my inbox gets cut off somewhere in the path to script1.  (And many lines in the crontab are significantly longer.)

### Options I've tried:

1. Piping to mail and setting subject etc per line (The -E preserves cron's default only-send-on-output behavior):

   ```
   0 */3 * * * /path/to/script1 | /path/to/script2 | /path/to/script3 2>&1 | mail -E -s "test subject" -S from="Cron Script2 <cronuser@myserver.com>" recipient@myserver.com
   ```

   This "works", but I want to centralize my changes in one place, and minimize how much I add to each cron line for readability
2. Using shell : (noop) command, which shows up first in the subject (note that the space after the : is important!):

   ```
   0 */3 * * *  : Descriptive Words; /path/to/script1 | /path/to/script2 | /path/to/script3
   ```

   Unfortunately there's still too much unnecessary that cron puts before "Descriptive Words" on the subject line, so this is still unusable.

### What I want to create:

Something generic, like this:

```
0 */3 * * * /path/to/script1 | /path/to/script2 | /path/to/script3 2>&1 | coolmailer.pl
```

coolmailer.pl would build the subject line by getting the commands on that cron line, strip out the paths and arguments, and email me this (optionally only if there's a fail in any of the scripts):

```
SUBJECT: script1 | script2 | script3
FROM: Cron Script3<noreply@myserver.com>
(actual results of the command /path/to/script1 | /path/to/script2 | /path/to/script3)
```

As a bonus, I'd also love to say whether any of the previous commands (script1 or script2) failed on the subject line.

This has turned out to be... way more complicated than I expected.

### Challenges:

1. Find a way for a pipeline member (coolmailer) to know the other
   members of the pipeline.

There's an ingenious method for 1 here using lsof [how-do-you-determine-the-actual-command-that-is-piping-into-you](https://superuser.com/questions/244413/how-do-you-determine-the-actual-command-that-is-piping-into-you) but it also sometimes finds commands started by the scripts in my pipeline (ie if script1 forks processes or does system calls, those show up too any time they take long enough to complete.)  Ditto for the method using process groups at the same link.

2. Find a way for a pipeline member (coolmailer) to know the results of
   other members of the pipeline.  (I realize this may not be possible at all, but the lsof hack gives me hope.)

Any better way?  Does the fact that I'm running from cron buy me anything?  Part of me wants to combine the lsof strategy with grepping through `crontab -l` results, but that just seems too kludgy and prone to errors.

### Caveats:

1. I can have changes made to my account, but I can't make changes that
   would effect all users. I.e. if there's a way to change cron's
   mailing format server-wide, that doesn't help.
2. I can't realistically update every script called to handle emailing its own results, even if that's probably the "right" way.
3. I know about the `mail -s -E -S` options, but would prefer to have a single place to change things.  Also, I really want to find a way to get the pipeline.
4. Language used now for "coolmailer" is Perl, but I'll try anything

### My first attempt:

(which works, except it often also shows other commands started inside my scripts, which means it doesn't work)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $pgid=`ps -o pgid= -p $$`;
my $lsofout = `/usr/sbin/lsof -g $pgid`;
my @otherpids = `echo "$lsofout" | awk '\$5 == "1w" { print \$2 }'`;
my @longcmds;
my @shortcmds;

foreach my $pid (@otherpids) {
  chomp($pid);
  if (my $cmd = `ps -o cmd= -p $pid 2>/dev/null`) {
    chomp($cmd);
    push @longcmds, $cmd;
    next;
  }
}
my $cmdline = join (' | ',@longcmds);

foreach my $cmd (@longcmds) {
  $cmd =~ s/(\/\S+\/)(\S+)/$2/g;
  push @shortcmds, $cmd;
}
my $subj = join('|',@shortcmds);

print "SUBJ:$subj\n";
print "CMDLINE: $cmdline\n";

# and now do some mail stuff
```

### And final version, based on suggestion by Jhnc

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# cronmgr.pl -- understand cron emails for once

# usage: 0 */3 * * * cronmgr.pl cd blah\; /path/to/script1 \| /path/to/script2 \| /path/to/script3
# note that ; | & in any cronmgr.pl line must be backslashed to run!

use strict;
use IPC::Cmd qw[can_run run run_forked];

my $CMDLINE = join(' ',@ARGV);
my( $success, $error_message, $full_buf, $stdout_buf, $stderr_buf ) =
        run( command => $CMDLINE, verbose => 0 ); # verbose = 0 means don't output normally, capture all output

my ($stdout, $stderr);
$stdout = join "", @$stdout_buf;
$stderr = join "", @$stderr_buf;

my $emailsubject;

if( $success ) {
    if ($stdout eq '' && $stderr eq '') { # if there's no output, don't send any email!
        exit;
    }
} else {
    print "CMD FAIL!\n$error_message\nSTDERR:\n$stderr";
    $emailsubject = "FAIL:$error_message";
}

# etc etc
```

(Edited for clarity re goals and why options attempted so far aren't sufficient.)

Comment: Have you tried to move this long line of scripts to a separate script?

Comment: @UjinT34 I'm trying hard to minimize changes to existing crontab because there are so many crons.  (See caveat 2, which should maybe be caveat 1.) 
 Also, even compressing into a separate script doesn't solve the issue with the current email subject getting cut off in the first path - I really need the ability to edit the subject and/or change the from.

Comment: can you list all your cronjobs with `crontab -l` or are they stored elsewhere (eg. /etc/cron.*/*)?

Comment: @jww - fair enough. Edited for clarity.  (The issue with neither is actual errors, but failure to resolve the problem statement effectively.)

Comment: @jhnc - yes to `crontab -l`.  I mention toward the end that I've considered combining the info culled from `lsof` with `crontab -l`, but I can't think of a way to make that error-proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### determining the pipeline

If you always invoke `coolmailer.pl` with a unique argument then you can simply grep it from your list of cronjobs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

$ENV{PATH} = '/sensible:/path';

my ($pipeline) = grep /\|\s+$0\s+$ARGV[0]/, `crontab -l`;
$pipeline ||= "oops";

# ... mung $pipeline ...

# ... do mail stuff ...
```

---

### checking pipe failure

If you rewrite your cronjob entries from:

```
/path/to/script1 | /path/to/script2 | /path/to/script3 2>&1 | coolmailer.pl
```

to:

```
coolermailer /path/to/script1 \| /path/to/script2 \| /path/to/script3
```

then you could construct the pipeline manually and have control over pipe member status information. (This also gives you the pipeline directly, although you then have to construct it before it will run.)

For example, with a bash implementation, you might make use of `eval` and `PIPESTATUS`. With Perl, you might use `results()` from [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/IPC-Run/lib/IPC/Run.pm#results)

Comment: Thank you @jhnc, this put me on the right track!  Final working script solution posted above.